# How to get a dictionary of arguments passed to a python method?

Tags: python, dictionary, class, local-variables

For simple functions we can use

```
def my_func(a, b):
    print(locals())
```

...that will return `{a: 1, b: 2}` if function called with `my_func(a=1, b=2)`.

**How can I get the same dictionary if `my_function` was a class method?***

Comment: You can also call `locals()` within a class (or instance) method. (It will also contain the class or instance object passed to the method.)

Comment: But if I use it in an inherited class, it returns too much stuff. If I want to unpack the dict for another function/method call, it breaks everything. Is there a way to get just the local method arguments?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `co_varnames` and `__defaults__` together in a `dict`ionary comprehension to get what we want:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    
    def some_method(self, a=0, b=1):
        return a + b

print(Foo.some_method.__code__.co_varnames)
print(Foo.some_method.__defaults__)
print({key: value for key, value in zip(Foo.some_method.__code__.co_varnames[1:], Foo.some_method.__defaults__)})
```

Outputs:

```
('self', 'a', 'b')
(0, 1)
{'a': 0, 'b': 1}
```

If `some_method` is a `classmethod` we can do the same thing:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    
    @classmethod
    def some_method(cls, a=0, b=1):
        return a + b

print(Foo.some_method.__code__.co_varnames)
print(Foo.some_method.__defaults__)
print({key: value for key, value in zip(Foo.some_method.__code__.co_varnames[1:], Foo.some_method.__defaults__)})
```

We can also use `Foo`'s `instance`:

```
instance = Foo()
print(instance.some_method.__code__.co_varnames)
print(instance.some_method.__defaults__)
print({key: value for key, value in zip(instance.some_method.__code__.co_varnames[1:], instance.some_method.__defaults__)})
```

But this is assuming the arguments have `__default__` values that are inputted into the `def`inition:

```
def some_method(self, a=0, b=1):
    ...
```

Otherwise if `some_method` has arguments without `__default__` values:

```
def some_method(self, a, b):
    ...
```

then `print(Foo.some_method.__defaults__)` and `print(instance.some_method.__defaults__)` outputs:

```
None
```